# How to get unmounted disk partitions in Places automatically?

Tags: dolphin, void-linux

I've 4 partitions on `/dev/sda`. During installation I've mounted `/dev/sda2` on `/`,  `/dev/sda1` on `/boot/efi`, didn't to anything for `/dev/sda3` as well as `/dev/sda4`, that's what I did for all linux distros so far with plasma-desktop and I always got those listed on the left side (Places) of dolphin. I just had to click and put password to access those partitions BUT on void I don't see those in "Places" and to access those I've to mount those manually each time I start the system. There're no entries for those in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=c42ga189-e151-4g95-a5ee-5e6d360d796c / ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=01C2-0E3D /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 2
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

How can I get those in "Places" automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Actually that was easy!

I'd to add two more entries in `/etc/fstab` in this way:

```
UUID=c42ga189-e151-4g95-a5ee-5e6d360d796c / ext4 defaults 0 1
UUID=01C2-0E3D /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 2
UUID=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx /media/500GiB ext4 defaults 0 3
UUID=yyy-yyy-yyy-yyy-yyy /media/1TiB ext4 defaults 0 4
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,nosuid,nodev 0 0
```

and add entries in "Places" with link to the location and icon.